# Why my string to decimal conversion failed in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
SELECT dsr,
  REPLACE(json_extract(JSON_EXTRACT(dsr, "$.*"), "$[0]"), '%', '') as ret1,
  CONVERT(REPLACE(json_extract(JSON_EXTRACT(dsr, "$.*"), "$[0]"), '%', ''), DECIMAL(10,2)) as ret2
FROM shops WHERE dsr IS NOT null LIMIT 1;
```

Result:

```
dsr: {"x": "44.92%", "y": "36.98%", "z": "27.10%"}
ret1: "44.92"
ret2: 0.00
```

I just tried to convert `ret1`("44.92") to decimal, but it gives `0.00`, which 44.92 is expected.

Could any one please give me some suggestions?

Comment: What part of your query is supposed to do such conversion?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `Convert(xxx,  DECIMAL(10,2))`, which xxx is "44.92"(`REPLACE(json_extract(JSON_EXTRACT(dsr, "$.*"), "$[0]"), '%', '')`)

Comment: Ah, right, you mean `ret2` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CONVERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) is not a general-purpose text parsing solution, it just makes conversions when they're straightforward. It ignores leading white-space and trailing non-numeric chars, but that's all:

```
SELECT
CONVERT('44.92', DECIMAL(10,2)),
CONVERT('44.92cm', DECIMAL(10,2)),
CONVERT('   44.92', DECIMAL(10,2)),
CONVERT('mmm44.92', DECIMAL(10,2)),
CONVERT('"44.92"', DECIMAL(10,2));
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
| 44.92 | 44.92 | 44.92 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

So you should get rid of the leading double-quote rather than the trailing percent sign:

```
SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE('"44.92%"', '"', ''), DECIMAL(10,2));
```